# Windows EventLog XML Query using wildcard

Tags: xml, windows, event-log, event-viewer

I am using an agent (NxLog) that is getting the logs directly from the Windows EventLog.
My goal here is to gather MSSQLServer logs; the agent is using windows built-in XML query to get them.

```
<QueryList>
    <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
        <Select Path="Application">*[System[Provider[@Name='MSSQL$Instance' or @Name='MSSQL$Instance$AUDIT'] and (Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3)]]</Select>
        <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='MSSQL$Instance' or @Name='MSSQL$Instance$AUDIT'] and (Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3)]]</Select>
    </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Since the MSSQL instance name will be different on each servers, I'd like to use a wildcard.
My issue is that I can't seem to use it inside the query.

I found this thread [Filtering events in Event Viewer using a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871384/filtering-events-in-event-viewer-using-a-regex) but it wasn't the answer i'm looking for.

Is there any special interaction to use a Wildcard inside this query ? If not, do you have any method to pass through this problem ?

Thanks